# PHP AJAX - count online users

Tags: php, ajax

I want no of online user in admin page using php
I have tried hard
this is my user home page:home.php

```
{function updatetime(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'update-status.php',
        success:function(data){

        }
    });
}
setInterval(updatetime,30000);}
```

update-status.php

```
$a=$_SESSION['user'];
$p="update user set logg='".time()."' where userid='$a'";
 mysqli_query($con,$p);
```

In admin page: adhome.php

```
{function online()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:'online.php',
        success:function(data){
            $(#rcon).html(data);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(online,30000);}
```

online.php:

```
$a=$_SESSION['user'];

    $m1="SELECT * from user where userid='$a'";

         echo $m2=mysqli_query($con,$m1) or die(mysqli_error($con));
          $m3=mysqli_num_rows($m2);
          $m4=mysqli_fetch_array($m3) or die(mysqli_error($con));
          if($m3==1)
           {
            $b=time()-$m4['logg'];
            if($b<(120))
                {
                $un= $m4['uname'];
                echo '<tr><td>'.$un.'</td></tr>';
                }
            }enter code here
```

It doesn't display error
I am not getting user in admin page bt db is updating 
and also please explain time()-$m4['logg']. I searched lot bt they didn't satisfied me.

Comment: So by the statement _I have tried hard_ what you actually mean is you have copied a lot of code and now you have found some you dont actually understand you want someone to explain it to you. Why not ask the person from whom you _borrowed it_

Comment: The `online.php` code in nonscense, so start by thinking exactly what you actually want that code to do and start again. I believe the process is called _ReFactoring_

Comment: i am able to do it using session. Bt I want to try using ajax. Honestly i don't know ajax. I am just learning it.Can u explain me with ajax?

Comment: Start by reading this http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html

Comment: Your javascript is not necessarily the big issue. `online.php` is not doing anything like what it probably shoud be doing

Answer (score -1):

PHP and Ajax is an bad idea to count the current online users, because it can xreate an high CPU and RAM usag.

An better solution is node.js with socket.io.
(http://socket.io)

With socket.io you can create really fast an online user counter without any big Server and Bandwith usage.

Stats:
Node.js and Socket.io can handle easyly more than 5.000 connections with about 12MB/s Bandwith and 16GB RAM and an Inter I7 Processor

Comment: Yes 16GB Ram is correct so I read it. It also can handle 600.000 Connections with an better Server http://www.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/

Comment: Yea I was just commenting that 16Gig of RAM is not a small amout of RAM, its a large amount of RAM specially if he in on a shared hosting plan,

Comment: Plus the guy is having enough trouble with the most basic PHP and javascript, whats he going to think of socket.io Keep the answers real man!

Comment: Good for you. Just remember not everybody has a Daddy with lots of money

Comment: :D ok thats right. But with the Daddy is not right. He give me the idea to look behind everything but I learned the rest myself